# Audio amplifier circuit explanation

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, amplifier, basic

Recently, I am working with amplifier circuits but circuits available online for an op-amp have some extra components with respect to what we learn in textbooks.

I know the basic amplifier components and their functioning, for example, Feedback resister, decoupling capacitors and I know how we control the gain, what is inverting and non-inverting input, and all other aspects which we learn in basic op-amp circuits. For example,

[image: Basic amplifier schematic]

Now, can anybody please explain why we are using some extra capacitor, diodes, and resistors (C1, C2, R1, R2, C3, R3, D1, D2, R6, C4, C5) in the following TDA2030 amplifier circuit.
What do they do? Why we are using them in the circuit? How changing the values affect the output? etc. These questions will help me and others to gain practical knowledge and modify the circuit by our own understanding.

**Please Note:**

1. I know how the capacitor, resistors, diodes, op-amp, etc works. I know basic electronics.
2. I know that extra components (C1, C2, R1, R2, C3, R3, D1, D2, R6, C4, C5) are used to control the noise and improve audio quality.  But, I want to know even more.
3. Please don't comment on why I am using TDA2030 IC.

**Thank you**

[image: schematic]

Comment: The chip datasheet includes a list of what each component in an example circuit does. Have you read the datasheet?

Comment: The TDA2030 is not an operational amplifier.  It is a power amplifier.  They are two very different things.

Comment: What part of Sect 4.3 did you understand?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thank you, I didn't check it. It helped

Comment: .... also, please don't use material that uses "IC 741" to describe "an opamp". The 741 is a very specific opamp, and it's a bad opamp, too. If your material confuses "opamp" with "specific opamp", the material is written by something without a firm grasp of what they're writing. If it uses "741" as "opamp that you would use in practice", the material is at least 30 years old and seeing it's on the internet, has been copied by someone who doesn't fully understand what they're copying. Either way, get better learning material.

Comment: "Please don't comment on why I am using TDA2030 IC." is a **red flag**. You know something is wrong with what you're doing (or at least, you believe that  you'll have to defend what you're doing), but you don't have arguments that you could simply put in your question to explain why you're doing it. So, probably, you're using something you shouldn't for some reason. Not wanting to discuss that reason will not make that reason go away. This sentence makes your question actively worse!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is answered by the section in the datasheet where the circuit is from.